# JQuery Mobile validate method not working

Tags: jquery, validation, node.js, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I used jquery validate plugin([plugin page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Isn.27t_that_nice_and_easy.3F)) in my jqm project.I included the plugin file and set validate on pageshow. Here is my script.js file:

```
$("body").delegate("div[data-role*='page']", "pageshow", function(){

$("#error").message({type:"error"});
$("#info").message();

$("#home").validate();

});
```

I included this file in my layout:

```
 script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.validate.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/script.js')
```

I added the classes to my inputs

```
input.input.required.email(id='email',type='text',value='',placeholder='name@email.com',name='email')
```

but it doesn't work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile does not support the validation plugin. Took awhile for me to figure this out but I had to write my own.